# Crontab command cannot be executed. Error PAM configurations

Tags: cron, redhat-enterprise-linux, crontab, pam

Here's the command that I would like to execute but it seems not to work.

```
[mdubois@veloce ~]$ crontab -l

Autorisation refusée
You (mdubois) are not allowed to access to (crontab) because of pam configuration.
```

below is my /etc/pam.d/crond file content

```
#
# The PAM configuration file for the cron daemon
#
#
# No PAM authentication called, auth modules not needed

account    required   pam_access.so
account    include    password-auth
session    required   pam_loginuid.so
session    include    password-auth
auth       include    password-auth
```

I cannot detect the error because it doesn't appear on the log file of the crontab

```
    [root@veloce ~]# tail -f /var/log/cron
Jul  2 16:01:01 veloce CROND[7482]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul  2 16:01:01 veloce run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[7482]: starting 0anacron
Jul  2 16:01:01 veloce run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[7491]: finished 0anacron
Jul  2 16:10:01 veloce CROND[8611]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul  2 16:20:01 veloce CROND[9940]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jul  2 16:26:45 veloce crond[10807]: (CRON) STARTUP (1.4.4)
Jul  2 16:26:45 veloce crond[10807]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 71% if used.)
Jul  2 16:26:45 veloce crond[10807]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Jul  2 16:26:45 veloce crond[10807]: (CRON) INFO (@reboot jobs will be run at computer's startup.)
Jul  2 16:30:01 veloce CROND[11312]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
```

I'm running RedHat 6.6 Santiago on my server.

It would be great if someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

PS: I have already included the user id in the /etc/cron.allow file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved just login directly with the user (in my case, using Putty).

Before the first login, tried changing access.conf and didn't work.

Just after add a *password* to the user and changed you shell to *bash* that solved my PAM configuration error, so I can finnally return the user to a non-shell and with `su userInTrouble` from ***root user*** I could made changes in cron with `crontab -e`

I'm using Centos 7 with Selinux in Permissive mode.

Comment: This same thing happened to me. I made exact snapshots of one of my servers and crontab did not work on the new copy. I had to ssh as root in order for this to work. I'm not completely sure why this happened, so if anyone has an explanation it would be extremely useful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the user to use crontab by modifying the file /etc/security/access.conf.

Insert these two lines

```
  # Allow the dubois user to run cron jobs
  +: dubois : cron crond :0
```

in the above mentioned file, **above** these two lines:

```
  # Deny all other users access by any means.
  -: ALL : ALL
```

which block all other users. Make sure you reboot your machine, afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [FreeIPA](https://www.freeipa.org/) you will need to create a Host-Based Access Control (HBAC) rule in order to allow the user to access the crond service on that host.

See [Defining Host-Based Access Control Rules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Identity_Management_Guide/hbac-rules.html) for specific details.

Answer (score 0):

Check if user's authentication token expired

```
sudo chage -l user
Last password change                                : Nov 29, 2018
Password expires                                    : Feb 27, 2019
Password inactive                                   : never
Account expires                                     : never
Minimum number of days between password change      : 7
Maximum number of days between password change      : 90
Number of days of warning before password expires   : 7
```

Change the user password expires

```
sudo chage -I -1 -m 0 -M 99999 -E -1 user
```

Hope this works